# Wrong resolution leading to a correct answer

Tags: integration

A video by blackpenredpen has come out recently, where this integral was proposed to solve (I will just copy what he wrote):
$\int_{-1}^1 \cos x\cos^{-1}x$d$x=$
$=2\int_0^1\cos x\cos^{-1}x$d$x$
$=\left[2\sin x\sin^{-1}\right]_0^1x$=
$=2\sin1\sin^{-1}1^{(*)}$
Right after that, he said this approach was wrong and showed how to solve this integral correctly, getting a finger answer of $\pi\sin 1$. But, he said, $\sin \frac{\pi}{2}=1\rightarrow\sin^{-1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, which means that the answer $^{(*)}$ was right, although the resolution itself was wrong.
So my question is: are there other definite integrals (not necessarily on opposite endpoints) such that, applying the following non-existing rules:
- if a function is even, then its inverse function is even as well;
- the integral of a product is the product of the integrals of the factors;
- given a function, the integral of its inverse function is the inverse of the integral of that function
which don't work for the integrand function, the final answer is correct anyway?